# How to track response time of saving/ submitting/ editing/ deleting forms in an application?

Tags: selenium, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, manual-testing

I am testing a windows application which is very slow but I couldn't figure that out why my application is taking a lot of time while submitting/ saving any form or uploading/ deleting document and editing forms. I need to track by automation that how much time my application is taking for the same with different data and in repetitions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Kanika

Answer (score 0):

Break the different types of activities "submitting/ saving any form or uploading/ deleting document and editing forms" into separate transaction types and pick one of them to start with.  The goal will be to Use JMeter to reproduce that activity in isolation. You may need to manually create a script or possibly use the JMeter proxy recorder to create a script.

You will also need to plan how you want to control the data side.  For example, run the test with a simple data case and check response times.  Then run the same test with a more complex data case.

Follow this process for each of the different transaction types in isolation.  Going through this process will put you in a nice place to begin finding where the slowdown is happening.